# proving that there are no odd perfect numbers

Tags: proof-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

I have been thinking about odd [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) and came upon an argument which must be invalid because it is too simple.

I would be very interested in understanding what is wrong with this argument.

Let:

- $s(x)$ be the [aliquot sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sum) for $x$.
- $p$ be an odd prime.

(1) If $p | x$, then $s(px) = s(x) + ps(x)$

(2) If $p \nmid x$, then $s(px) = s(x) + ps(x) + x$

(3) Assume that $px$ is an odd perfect number such that $s(px) = px$

(4) If $p | x$, then $px = s(x)(p+1)$ which is impossible since $p+1$ is even but $px$ is odd.

(5) If $p \nmid x$, then $px = s(x) + ps(x) + x$ and $x(p-1) = s(x)(p+1)$

(6) There exists integers $a$ and $b$ such that $2^a | (p-1)$ but $2^{a+1} \nmid (p-1)$ and $2^b | (p+1)$ but $2^{b+1} \nmid (p+1)$

(7)  $a \ne b$ since $4 | (p-1)(p+1)$ but $4 | (p-1)$ if and only if $4 \nmid (p+1)$ since $4 \nmid (4a-2)$ and $4 \nmid (4a+2)$

(8) $a > b$ since $x$ is odd.

(9) So, $s(x)$ is even

(10) $s(x)$ is only even if $x$ is not squarefree since:

> - Base Case: if $x$ is a prime then $s(x)=1$
> - Assume that if $x$ is squarefree, then $s(x)$ is odd.
> - Inductive Case: $s(px) = s(x) + ps(x) + x = $ odd + odd + odd = odd.

(11) If $x$ is not squarefree, there exists an prime $q$ where $q^2 | x$.

(12) But this is impossible, since we would have the case where $px = s\left(q(p\dfrac{x}{q}\right) = s\left(p\dfrac{x}{q}\right) + qs\left(p\dfrac{x}{q}\right) = s\left(p\dfrac{x}{q}\right)(q + 1)$ where $qx$ is odd but $(q+1)$ is even.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I figured it was  one of my assumptions!

Comment: Just in case you still do not know:  There is a known form that an odd perfect number must take and that is $N = q^k n^2$, where $q$ is the special / Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$, @LarryFreeman.

Comment: Yes, I found this same property and was very surprised.  I read through the Wikipedia article on perfect numbers and saw it confirmed.  Thanks so much for posting this. When I asked the question, I did not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions (1) fails in general. Pick $x=p^2$. Then $s(x)=1+p$, $s(px)=1+p+p^2$, so $s(xp)\neq s(p)+ps(x)$. I think it only holds if $x$ divides $p$ exactly once.